# Assembly code compilation error: file not recognized

Tags: gcc, assembly, cross-compiling, nasm

I am trying to compile an assembly code.

I used commands

```
nasm -f coff myMergeSort.asm
gcc driver.c myMergeSort.o asm_io.o -o merge
```

But i'm getting following error:

```
myMergeSort.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried using "obj" in place of "coff" but it gives a similar error.

using "elf" in place of "coff" gives following error:

```
myMergeSort.o: In function `main':
myMergeSort.asm:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/cchbsJLl.o:driver.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cchbsJLl.o: In function `main':
driver.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `asm_main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How could i fix it?

Comment: @Michael : Yeah i tried using elf, it gives the error "multiple definition of main", like i've posted in the question

Comment: Who's code is driver.c? Looks like it expects your assembly code to export a function named `asm_main` rather than `main`.

Answer (score 0):

in driver.c you probably have a call to asm_main, try adding 
extern return_type asm_main(Type1 name1, ..., Typen namen);

where return_type is replaced by the return type of the function and typei is the TYPE
of the parameter numbered i passed.